# The method setInt(int, int) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have to link my webpage to a jsp file but I'm getting some errors. I am somewhat an Intermediate btw. I have a MySQL database that I am meant to link the form that I fill out on my webpage but I either get this error (The method setInt(int, int) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)) or (Unable to connect to database)
Can anyone help?

jsp code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>AutoServe</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>form</h1>

<%


String first_name = request.getParameter("fname");
String last_name = request.getParameter("lname");
String email_form = request.getParameter("email");
String phone_form = request.getParameter("phone");
String address_form = request.getParameter("address");
String year_form = request.getParameter("car_year");
String make_form = request.getParameter("make");
String model_form = request.getParameter("model");
String colour_form = request.getParameter("colour");

int car_year = Integer.parseInt(year_form);



try {

java.sql.Connection cn;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webpage", "root", "passwordlivi");


PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
int updateQuery = 0;

String queryString = "INSERT INTO appointment(fname, lname, email, phone, address, car_year, make, model, colour) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


          pstatement = cn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                      pstatement.setString(1, first_name);
                      pstatement.setString(2, last_name);
                      pstatement.setString(3, email_form);
                      pstatement.setString(4, phone_form);
                      pstatement.setString(5, address_form);
                      pstatement.setInt(6, year_form);
                      pstatement.setString(7, make_form);
                      pstatement.setString(8, model_form);
                      pstatement.setString(9,    colour_form);



          updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();

                        if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
         <br>
               <TABLE style="background-color: #E3E4FA;" 
               WIDTH="30%" border="1">
                  <tr><th>Data is inserted successfully 
                in database.</th></tr>
               </table>
          <%
          }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable to connect to database.");

           }





%>

</body>
</html>
```

My database code

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>JDBC Connection example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>AutoServe.Inc</h1>

<%

java.sql.Connection cn;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cn = DriverManager.getConnection  ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webpage", "root", "passwordlivi");


ResultSet rst=null;
Statement stmt=null;

stmt=cn.createStatement();
rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from appointment ");



while(rst.next()){

%>

<p>
First Name: <%=rst.getString(1)%>  <br/>
Last Name: <%=rst.getString(2)%>  <br/>
Email Address: <%=rst.getString(3)%>  <br/>
Phone: <%=rst.getString(4)%>  <br/>
Address: <%=rst.getString(5)%>  <br/>
Year: <%=rst.getInt(6)%>  <br/>
Make : <%=rst.getString(7)%>  <br/>
Model: <%=rst.getString(8)%>  <br/>
Colour: <%=rst.getString(9) %> </br>


</p>

<%
}


%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn to read error messages. This one is perfectly clear. The method expects two ints and you are feeding it an int and a String. You can't be running to SO every time for problems like this or you'll never get anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `pstatement.setInt(6, year_form);` to`pstatement.setInt(6, car_year);`. You are trying to put a String into a method that requires an integer. The Code above already converted the String into an int.